# Reverse proxy on Apache server, without access to configuration files

Tags: php, node.js, apache, proxy

The hosting provider has their default Apache configuration running on port number 80. Since the Apache configuration can not be changed, Node applications running on the same server must be accessed using `domain.name:port`.

What kind of a reverse proxy can be used to intercept incoming requests and forward them to a specific port? For example:

```
domain1.name:80 -> default (domain1dir/index.php)
domain2.name:80 -> localhost:8001 (NodeJS)
domain3.name:80 -> localhost:8002 (NodeJS)
```

Since Node can't listen on port number 80 in parallel with Apache, only PHP reverse-proxy springs to my mind. Does a relatively straight forward solution in PHP exist and are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: in the root folder of your website, create file named `.htaccess` with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain2.name
RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:8001{REQUEST_URI} [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain3.name
RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:8002{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

(This requires `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` to be enabled by your hosting provider)

Comment: Hi Dusan, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to check, if mod_proxy and mod_rewrite are enabled via the command line?

Comment: try `apachectl -M`